# Pandas reading CSV as single column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to load a large CSV file into Pandas, which I'm new to.

The input file should have 13 columns. Howeever, Pandas is reading all of the column headings as one heading, and then just collecting the first few columns of data.

The code I am using is;-

leases=pd.read_csv("/content/LEASES_FULL_2021_12.csv",  sep=',', delimiter=None, header=0, names=None, index_col=False, usecols=None, squeeze=False, engine="python")

The CSV is formatted as follows:-

Unique Identifier,Tenure,Register Property Description,County,Region,Associated Property Description ID,Associated Property Description,OS UPRN,Price Paid,Reg Order,Date of Lease,Term,Alienation Clause Indicator

"1608D08BFC5496E31C7926595EE2F1BE278ED436","Leasehold","19 Alcester Crescent, Clapton","GREATER LONDON","GREATER LONDON","501286752","19 ALCESTER CRESCENT, LONDON E5 9PX","10008240310","","2","13-02-1905","99 years from 25 December 1902","N"

"5D0FA4909B7C0FD9477C2275E1948C8F135E233F","Leasehold","7 Agnes Street, Limehouse","GREATER LONDON","GREATER LONDON","3125118","7 AGNES STREET, LONDON E14 7DG","6044926","","2","16-10-1866","99 years from 24 June 1862","N"

etc

The Dataframe then loads with one column as follows:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfStC.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a regular comma separated file, can you try removing other parameters and simply use leases=pd.read_csv("/content/LEASES_FULL_2021_12.csv")?

Comment: Try either to remove `sep` argument or try `sep='\fe50'`. Does it help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, I tried these to no avail sadly.

Comment: Can you share your file please (or at least the header line). I suspect a different character than comma.

Comment: Hi Corralien, the fil is over 2gb so I don't think I can upload it. However, I just opened it with Sublime Text and an extract is :-  "Unique Identifier,Tenure,Register Property Description,County,Region,Associated Property Description ID,Associated Property Description,OS UPRN,Price Paid,Reg Order,Date of Lease,Term,Alienation Clause Indicator
"1608D08BFC5496E31C7926595EE2F1BE278ED436","Leasehold","19 Alcester Crescent, Clapton","GREATER LONDON","GREATER LONDON","501286752","19 ALCESTER CRESCENT, LONDON E5 9PX","10008240310","","2","13-02-1905","99 years from 25 December 1902","N"

Comment: You don't need to upload 2Gb you just need to copy/paste 5 lines and share it. It's not possible to help you without the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading it a different way

```
  data = pd.read_csv(dir, sep=",")
```

or

```
  df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', names=["Name1", "Name2"])  #fill in columns names
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the solution, the first row of the CSV has no "" around each column name. Resolved now. Thanks for your help.